# Using nodes git-rev on Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, heroku, express

I'm using the node package [git-rev](https://www.npmjs.org/package/git-rev) to let my application output it's own version. Therefore, I created this method:

```
var git = require('git-rev');

module.exports = function (req, res) {
  git.long(function (commit) {
    git.branch(function (branch) {
      git.tag(function (tag) {
        res.json({
          'commit': commit,
          'branch': branch,
          'tag': tag
        });
      });
    });
  });
};
```

It works fine on my local machine, but on heroku, it just returns

```
{
  "commit": "",
  "branch": "",
  "tag": ""
}
```

My `package.json` contains `"git-rev": "~0.2.1"` as dependency and I could not find a hint in the heroku logs. Why is it not working on heroku?